# Is this relation antisymmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

3) Let S={0,1,2,4,6}. Test the following binary relation on S for reflexivity, symmetry, antisymmetry, and transitivity:

R={(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(4,4),(6,6),(0,1),(1,2),(2,4),(4,6)}

Don't worry about the other questions, just antisymmetry please. I'm taking an online class, and even though about half of the students have said it is, half of us have said it isn't and the professor hasn't commented on either.

The way I'm understanding it is that if there is even one element that doesn't satisfy antisymmetry than it is not antisymmetric. Other students are saying exactly the opposite, that you only need one element for antisymmetry, so (0,0) or (1,1) or (2,2) etc would make it antisymmetric. Perhaps I don't have a good enough grasp on antisymmetry in the first place but I've read our text and discussions on here about antisymmetry, but still having trouble.

Would appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Upon reading your question more closely, it almost seems as though your conception is that a relation $R$ is anti-symmetric if and only if *exactly one* of $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$ are in $R$ (assuming $a \not= b$).  That is not the case.  As Brian Scott's statement of the definition indicates, it is anti-symmetric so long as *at most one* of those is in $R$ (again assuming $a \not= b$).  It is possible for neither of them to be in $R$ without violating anti-symmetry.

Comment: @BrianTung yeah I think it's my understanding of the concept of antisymmetry in the first place that is hurting me. The fact that about half of my class is having the same issue didn't help, as it made me think I might be right. But I think I have a better understanding now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antisymmetry says that **if** $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$ **and** $\langle b,a\rangle\in R$, **then** $a=b$. In other words, it says that there do not exist two distinct elements $a$ and $b$ such that $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle b,a\rangle$ are both in $R$. Thus, whether pairs like $\langle a,a\rangle$ are in $R$ is irrelevant to the question of whether $R$ is antisymmetric.

Your relation **is** antisymmetric: the only elements that appear are $0,1,2,4$, and $6$, and no matter which two different ones you choose, at most one of the possible ordered pairs belongs to $R$. For instance, $\langle 0,1\rangle\in R$, but $\langle 1,0\rangle\notin R$. In the case of $1$ and $4$, neither $\langle 1,4\rangle$ nor $\langle 4,1\rangle$ is in $R$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints.** The relation $\leq$, with the usual meaning, is anti-symmetric.  A subset of an anti-symmetric relation is also anti-symmetric.

Alternatively, partial and total orders are anti-symmetric.  (This doesn't immediately help you because the relation isn't...well, it should be clear if you think about it why this doesn't directly help you, but *understanding* why partial and total orders are anti-symmetric may help you with this problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Antisymmetry is the property that: $$\forall x\,\forall y\; \Big(\big((\langle x,y\rangle\in R)\wedge (\langle y,x\rangle\in R)\big) \to (x=y)\Big)$$

This can also be expressed by the countapositive:
$$\forall x\,\forall y\; \Big((x\neq y)\to \big((\langle x,y\rangle\notin R)\vee (\langle y,x\rangle\notin R)\big)\Big)$$

Both of which are equivalent to: $$\neg\exists x\exists y\;\Big((x\neq y)\wedge (\langle x,y\rangle\in R)\wedge (\langle y,x\rangle\in R)\Big)$$

So, to claim antisymmetry it is necessary and sufficient to establish that there is no *counterexample* of two *distinct* entities that are symmetrically related.